# Reverse proxy setup on haproxy gives 500; wget on base server & nginx works

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, http-status-code-500

I am trying to setup haproxy as a reverse proxy for a server. I am on Centos.

The config goes like this:

```
global
   #log /dev/log local0
   #log /dev/log local1 notice
   log 127.0.0.1 local2 info
   log 127.0.0.1 local2 notice
   log 127.0.0.1 local2 debug
   chroot /var/lib/haproxy
   stats timeout 30s
   user haproxy
   group haproxy
   daemon

defaults
mode http
log global
option httplog
option dontlognull
option http-server-close
option forwardfor except 127.0.0.0/8
option redispatch
retries 3
timeout http-request 10s
timeout queue 1m
timeout connect 10s
timeout client 1m
timeout server 1m
timeout http-keep-alive 10s
timeout check 10s
maxconn 3000

frontend http_front
   bind *:801
   option forwardfor
   stats enable
   default_backend http_back

backend http_back
   mode http
   option httpchk
   option forwardfor
   http-send-name-header Host
   balance roundrobin
   server server1 stg-hostserv.com:80
```

But, if I do a wget against it, I am getting the below error.

```
# wget http://0.0.0.0:801
--2018-07-16 14:26:24--  http://0.0.0.0:801/
Connecting to 0.0.0.0:801... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2018-07-16 14:26:24 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.


     haproxy  -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -d
[WARNING] 197/200148 (13833) : config : frontend 'GLOBAL' has no 'bind' directive. Please declare it as a backend if this was intended.
Available polling systems :
      epoll : pref=300,  test result OK
       poll : pref=200,  test result OK
     select : pref=150,  test result FAILED
Total: 3 (2 usable), will use epoll.
Using epoll() as the polling mechanism.
00000000:http_front.accept(0004)=0006 from [127.0.0.1:60696]
00000000:http_front.clireq[0006:ffffffff]: GET / HTTP/1.1
00000000:http_front.clihdr[0006:ffffffff]: User-Agent: Wget/1.14 (linux-gnu)
00000000:http_front.clihdr[0006:ffffffff]: Accept: */*
00000000:http_front.clihdr[0006:ffffffff]: Host: 0.0.0.0:801
00000000:http_front.clihdr[0006:ffffffff]: Connection: Keep-Alive
00000000:http_back.srvrep[0006:0007]: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
00000000:http_back.srvhdr[0006:0007]: Content-Type: text/html
00000000:http_back.srvhdr[0006:0007]: Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
00000000:http_back.srvhdr[0006:0007]: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
00000000:http_back.srvhdr[0006:0007]: Date: Tue, 17 Jul 2018 12:02:00 GMT
00000000:http_back.srvhdr[0006:0007]: Connection: close
00000000:http_back.srvhdr[0006:0007]: Content-Length: 1208
00000001:http_front.clicls[0006:ffffffff]
00000001:http_front.closed[0006:ffffffff]
^C
[root@izp0w3tkx2yr8zhes26ajqz ~]#
```

I tried different config for the server and consistently hit 500 error. Wget to the base server works without any issues. 
I setup nginix to the same thing and it works beautifully. Just haproxy does not seem to work. The customer wants it on haproxy. :)

Can you please advise where I can look at to further debug. Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: You're not showing us logs or configuration that appear to match the test you claim to be making.  Where does the double `//` in `GET //app_themes/base...` come from?  What's in the HAProxy log and the back-end log?

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I did a few tests and must have mixed up the logs. Here are the matching ones.

Comment: Does your backend Microsoft-IIS/8.0 check `host` header? as you set `http-send-name-header Host`,  so request from HAProxy to stg-hostserv.com:80 looks like
`GET / HTTP/1.1 Host: izp0w3tkx2yr8zhes26ajqz`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. That option is one of the last that I added. Even without that option, I got the same error.

Comment: Can you check `curl http://stg-hostserv.com:80/ -H "Host: izp0w3tkx2yr8zhes26ajqz"` ?

Comment: Wow!! I got the same error.
  <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
  <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>

Comment: I tried changing the hostname and it did not fix.  :(
http-send-name-header stg-hostserv.com

Comment: curl -v http://stg-hostserv.com/ -H "Host: stg-hostserv.com" #Works
curl -v http://stg-hostserv.com/ -H "Host: dummy"  #Does not Work
curl -v http://0.0.0.0:801/ -H "Host: stg-hostserv.com"  #HAproxy endpoint Does not Work with correct hostname :(

Comment: If I change it to the below and pass the header as parameter it works..
 curl -v http://0.0.0.0:801/ -H "Host: stg-hostserv.com"
http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Host %[req.hdr(Host)]

Anyway I can avoid passing the host name and set it in the config? Please advise.

Comment: It worked when I set it up like this.
http-request set-header Host stg-hostserv.com

Thanks a ton guys. You are great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This update from nuster cache server helped solve the problem:

> Does your backend Microsoft-IIS/8.0 check `host` header? as you set `http-send-name-header Host`, so request from HAProxy to stg-hostserv.com:80 looks like `GET / HTTP/1.1 Host: izp0w3tkx2yr8zhes26ajqz`

HAProxy worked when I set:

```
http-request set-header Host stg-hostserv.com
```